# Change gnome-tweaks scaling factor in the terminal?

Tags: command-line, 20.04, gnome, fonts

I change the scaling factor often when I switch between laptop (1.4 to be able to see everything better) and laptop with second screen (back to 1.0)

The fastest way I've managed to do this now with as little mouse use as possible is opening gnome-tweaks through the command line, but then I have to go to fonts, and type the desired value there

Is there any command I could use that I could turn into an alias to make this process faster? Thanks.

I'm talking about the last option here:

[Gnome Tweaks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sNGfT.png)

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface text-scaling-factor 1.4
```

You could define an alias indeed. Another option is to bind such command to a shortcut key.